# How to check VPN Connectivity in iPhone

Tags: ios, vpn

I am new to this development.
I searched a lot over Internet but cant find any proper solution for it.
I want to check VPN connectivity available in my iPhone application as I am fetching data from client machine which is connected through VPN.
I did check if Internet connection is available but unable to check if VPN is connected or not.
Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna ping function, you can do something like this;

1. Setup a socket to your internal ip
2. Make the socket non block
3. Using select to check the socket status

It's working for me

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide me with any small code or library reference where I can implement same.

Answer (score 11):

I've just found another way to check VPN connection, which wasn't mentioned anywhere.
You can use getifaddrs() to get current network interfaces. 
Then iterate though them and check their names. If any of them contains **tap**,**tun** or **ppp** then user has connected VPN.

```
  - (BOOL)isVPNConnected
{
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while (temp_addr != NULL) {
            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , temp_addr->ifa_name];
            if ([string rangeOfString:@"tap"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [string rangeOfString:@"tun"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [string rangeOfString:@"ppp"].location != NSNotFound){
                return YES;
            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return NO;
}
```

UPD: on iOS 9 code above is not working. Interfaces are the same, no matter if VPN is connected or not. Try following code in this case:

```
 - (BOOL)isVPNConnected
{
    NSDictionary *dict = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
        NSArray *keys = [dict[@"__SCOPED__"]allKeys];
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            if ([key rangeOfString:@"tap"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [key rangeOfString:@"tun"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [key rangeOfString:@"ppp"].location != NSNotFound){
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me do I have to import any framework for this ? I mean #import ?

Comment: @harshalb I don't have them, works without. But you can try #include <ifaddrs.h>

Comment: @TimurSuleimanov both of your code snippets doesn't work anymore (I'm using iOS 10). Have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: All solutions based on __SCOPED__ don't work reliable with IPSec VPNs, even if you add 'ipsec' to the key detection logic.

Answer (score 6):

To fix Timur Suleimanov answer tested on iOS 11 you need to look for IPSec interface;

```
- (BOOL)isVPNConnected {
    NSDictionary *dict = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
    NSArray *keys = [dict[@"__SCOPED__"]allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        if ([key rangeOfString:@"tap"].location != NSNotFound ||
            [key rangeOfString:@"tun"].location != NSNotFound ||
            [key rangeOfString:@"ipsec"].location != NSNotFound ||
            [key rangeOfString:@"ppp"].location != NSNotFound){
            return YES;;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Swift Version of the code

```
var isVPNConnectd : Bool {
    get {
        if let dict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()?.takeRetainedValue() as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,
            let keys = (dict["__SCOPED__"] as? [String : AnyObject])?.keys {
            for key in keys {
                if key.range(of: "tap") != nil ||
                    key.range(of: "tun") != nil ||
                    key.range(of: "ipsec") != nil ||
                    key.range(of: "ppp") != nil {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        else {
            return false
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping or Lookup an address that should only be available on the VPN, if you can connect the VPN is in use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide me some piece of code or logic to lookup for an address which would not take much time for user to wait. Thanks..